# MariaDB + .net core in linux or docker is failing for high load scenario. Works when from local Windows dev machine

Tags: docker, .net-core, mariadb

I think that I've pinpointed my issue, and it looks like it is environmental.

Basically one of the apps that is doing a lot of data computation (ML) is having issue with accessing that data in a high load scenario.

I have .net core 3.0 app using Worker to connect to MySQL and retrieve data (~ 4000-5000 queries per second for ~ 60 seconds).

When I am running it locally via dotnet run it seems to be working fine (never saw an error). However when I try to run it via docker (microsoft 3.101 image or bionic 3.101 sdk/runtime) or directly from Ubuntu with 3.1 sdk, I will start getting number of weird random errors (i.e. table doesn't exist, operation cancelled, often app was freezing without an error (the thread on Hangfire, when running without it would stop acking to RabbitMQ etc. so weird state)).

Now I am running it without Hangfire, with specified threads that are started via worker.

Weird thing is that all errors will be having paths

```
".... in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\...\xxxxx.cs"
```

However this is happening on Linux / Docker linux image, so not sure how it can even know about existence of C:...

It is totally killing me for last 72 hours as this is a big new feature that is using ML to process huge amount of data on hourly basis, and basically MySQL is not working with it in either environment beside dev (local machine with windows).

Comment: Keep in mind that Docker (or any other virtualization) adds a layer to all operations.  For thousands of qps, you should consider using a standalone database server.

Comment: MySQL is a standalone. The issue was happening on the docker client app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by a corrupted library built from a source. Developer somehow managed to use .net core / .net framework as a target corrupting whole project. However in Windows it worked fine.

There was also another similar library used by mistake in one of source libraries... That is why it worked in most cases...

Solved by removing corrupted library, using different build that would be free of corrupted target.